# Mean and variance preserving skewness 'spread'

Tags: probability, distributions, data-transformation

This is essentially a request for references in case what I am describing is studied somewhere, to avoid trying to come up with the machinery myself.

Heuristically, what I want to do is take some distribution with (continuous, say) pdf $f$ with domain (0,1), apply some transformation $g$ to it so that the resulting distribution $g\circ f$ has

- The same mean as (the distribution described by) $f$
- The same variance as (the distribution described by) $f$
- ''More'' mass in the right tail, and less in the left, than before. (I am for now taking skewness as this measure).

My questions: what properties would such a function $g$ need to have?

Is skewness the right measure of relative mass in the tails?

Comment: The same mean and variance are trivial. Consider that so long as there is a variance you can standardise to mean 0 and SD 1 and then map back to the original mean and SD (or variance). But there isn't a universal function otherwise. First of all, consider a distribution with two spikes with probability $p$  and $1 - p$. No one-to-one transformation can do anything more than change the sign of the skewness. Other awkward distributions exist. Second, more general transformation families such as Box-Cox usually make assumptions about the support of the variable and aren't guaranteed to work well.

Comment: I've added a tag that is crucial here.

Comment: The distributions I would want to transform are bounded in $[0,1]$ and assuming continuity is fine. Does this make it amenable to a general family and/or remove the awkwardness of distributions?

Comment: That restriction isn't in the question -- and so it would be helpful if it were. 0 and 1 being possible rules out many useful transformations such as logit.

Comment: I’ll edit so it’s (0,1). The endpoints arnt realistic.

Comment: Here's an interesting factoid. Logit makes all beta distributions unimodal. That won't stop them being skew, but I'd argue that isn't essential.

Comment: Perhaps I’ve been unclear. I want them to be skew. And want to continuously change the skewness leaving first and second moments fixed)

Comment: I would say that more mass in one tail and less in another means a change in skewness with mean and variance invariant.  It’s a fight between you being unclear and me not now able  to guess what you’re after.

Comment: I didn't entirely understand your second to last comment, speicifically about what wasn't essential and to what end that something wasn't essential. 
But my question is about whether there is a nice way to characterize a function that changes the skewness of a distribution without affecting it's mean and variance. I am a bit unsure about how logit functions making beta distributions unimodal relates.

Comment: I have thought more about it and I think actually the question should be in terms of quantiles, not moments. That is, what transformation can be applied to a distribution that increases its skewness (perhaps now not in the third moment sense, but some measure) while holding constant the median, or perhaps in general just holding constant the $/alpha$ quantile for some $/alpha$.

Comment: This question is too general to hope for references: the properties $g$ needs to have are precisely those you have specified. A formulation in terms of quantiles is also general, but admits a nice picture: the graphs of the two CDFs must pass through a set of specified points (the quantiles), whence $g$ can be formulated as a general transformation on each interval between successive quantiles that preserves the cadlag property of the graphs--of which the principal feature is they must not decrease when moving left to right.  And that's all one can say.